# Loading intent based on pref

Tags: java, android

I want to load a pref value and then decide, whether I load activity A or activity B in the intent.

Something like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean pref1 = prefs.getBoolean("pref1", true);

// Pseudocode
if (pref1) {
      class nextScreen = aActivity.class;
} else {
      class nextScreen = bActivity.class;
}

Intent goToMainActivity = new Intent(this, nextScreen);
```

I'm very new to android and java, so please be patient.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How I can archive this. I mean the "class next Screen"  thing is not a valid code. I searched a lot, but did not find a fitting answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, to use a `variable` outside a condition, you need to *declare* it before entering the condition:

```
type variable; // declaration
if (condition) {
    variable = value1; // assign a specific value
else {
    variable = value2; // assign an other value
}
// use 'variable' with the value setted
```

Thus, you will be able to use it in the `Intent` after the condition. Then in order to use an intent in your case, you need to know what's the type for the second element. In this example as you provide, it's a [`Class` object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) and the method used is `public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`.
Therefore, it should be easy as:

```
Class nextScreen = null;
if (pref1) {
  nextScreen = aActivity.class;
} else {
  nextScreen = bActivity.class;
}

if (nextScreen != null) {
    Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(this, nextScreen);
}
```